# Programmatically add user permission to a list in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, permissions, moss

How do I programmatically add user permissions to a list in Sharepoint? I want to add the permission "Contribute" to a user or group for a certain list. I'm using C#.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this using the [SPRoleAssignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sproleassignment.aspx) object, e.g.

```
// Assuming you already have SPWeb and SPList objects
...
SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment("dom\\user", "user@dom", "user", "some notes");
SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
if (!myList.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
{
    myList.BreakRoleInheritance(true); // Ensure we don't inherit permissions from parent
} 
myList.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
myList.Update();
```

Comment: I think your comment "Ensure we don't inherit permissions from parent" is not consistent with the code, it should be myList,BreakRoleInheritance(false) for that.

Comment: @csgero - not according to MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.breakroleinheritance.aspx