# Set permission for user programmatically? (sharepoint)

Tags: sharepoint

I am using the following code to set permission for groups when I create a site:

```
            // Assign Site Owner role to the selected users
            string siteOwnerGroup = null;
            string siteOwnerRole = null;
            foreach (ListItem item in lbSiteOwner.Items)
            {
                siteOwnerGroup = item.Text.ToString();
                siteOwnerRole = "Full Control";

                SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(web.SiteGroups[siteOwnerGroup]);
                SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection roleDefinition = roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings;

                roleDefinition.Add(web.RoleDefinitions[siteOwnerRole]);
                web.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
                web.Properties[siteOwnerGroup] = siteOwnerRole;
                web.Properties.Update();
            }
```

Shouldn't it be easy to change this to set permission for users in the lbSiteOwner listbox instead?

I tried

```
            SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(web.SiteUsers[siteOwnerGroup]);
```

But it doesn't work, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following solution will hold true in your case as well in place of list use web
[Programatically add user permission to a list in Sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358647/programatically-add-user-permission-to-a-list-in-sharepoint)